# HOW i have to procceed to read and understand a script php with many folder

Tags: php

I don't know where to start reading php file project folder  ,index..config... 
IF you have tutorial or site please help me 
I just want to understand it how it work ... etc 
Thank you so much

EDIT : i'am not searching for learn a php 
I search for a good method to understand project coded in php

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/ this is good for beginner

Comment: w3schools is not a good reference: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a good debug tool. Netbeans is good, There is one more Aptana. I use the PhpEdit its easy debugging in it. start from the index.php file if its a MVC and has a login page, start from there.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the `index.php` file.
Search for `include` and `require` calls. and check those files next.

I would say there is no common way of understanding software.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean websites to learn PhP then there are multiple that all have great starter information.

[W3Schools - PhP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)

[PhP.net - Documentation](http://www.php.net/docs.php)

Should help! Also StackOverflow is an obvious for questions when a code issue arises or seeking general information on a specific aspect. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using IDE, in most of them the navigation between files is very easy, I prefer netbeans PHP if you have include or require and you click on the path with your mouse while holding the Ctrl key it will open the file, which make it very easy navigation.
https://netbeans.org/features/php/